# Is there a way to compare two variable with the comparator stored as a string

Tags: python, comparator

I am looking for a function that allows me to do something like this:

```
a = 3
b = 5
comparator = ">"
result = some_function(comparator, a, b)
```

comparator could be any comparator (>, >=, <, <=, ==, !=); a and b could be any string or any number

I could do something with a huge condition list but some function might already exist (but couldn't find it)

Comment: And i'm going to avoid doing a string that I run as someone could do some crazy things when providing a or b

Comment: are you looking for the `operator` module in the standard library?

Comment: as far as i understand here i need to know already which comparator i will use which is not the case, but would be something like this yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the expected strings to their functional counterparts.

```
import operator

comparators = {
  ">": operator.gt,
  "<": operator.lt,
  # etc
}

result = comparators[comparator](a, b)
```

Comment: i'm surprised `operator` dosen't provide these strings in an attribute like `operator.gt.__symbol__` or something?

Comment: I think it's because it's rare that you would have an arbitrary but unknown operator in a variable `f`, and need access to a symbol for it. For building a mapping like his, either you already know that `operator.gt.__symbol__` should be `">"`, in which case you should just write that explicitly, or you want to recognize some *other* symbol for the operator (think `"≥"` for `operator.ge`), in which case you need to be explicit anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions):

```
import operator

symbol_map = {
    '>': operator.gt,
    '>=': operator.ge,
    # and so on
}

def some_function(op, a, b):
    return symbol_map[op](a, b)
```

Comment: `operator` provides non-dunder names for "public" use.

Comment: @chepner, yeah, and the documentation also says: "The variants without the double underscores are preferred for clarity.", so away the underscores go!

Comment: Kind of makes me wonder why the module ever exported the dunder names instead of the normal ones in the first place :)